# using backbone with third party api

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to use backbone to grab hold of an instagram feed. This doesn't require authenticating the user, it is pulling a public feed available through:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user_id>/media/recent/?client_id=<client_id>`

I've gotten as far as outputting the JSON response into the console, but I'm unable to make it display on my page.

In the code below, I use fetchData to grab the feed, and I'd like to eventually get it to a point where render outputs everything stylized on `#social`. However, despite setting the feed property to the JSON response, `render` still returns an empty object. `console.log` in `fetchData` however displays the proper information.

```
var social = {}

social.Instagram = Backbone.Model.extend();

social.InstagramFeed = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: social.Instagram,
url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user_id>/media/recent/?client_id=<client_id>',
parse: function(response) {
    return response.results;
},
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    var params = _.extend({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: this.url,
        processData: false
    }, options);
    return $.ajax(params);
}
});

social.InstagramView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#social',
feed: {},
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new social.InstagramFeed();
    this.fetchData();
    this.render();
},
render: function() {
    console.log(this.feed);
},
fetchData: function() {
    this.collection.fetch({
        success: function(collection, response) {

            // console.log(response);
            feed = response;
            // console.log(this.feed);

        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("failed to find instagram feed...");
        }
    });
}
});

social.instagramview = new social.InstagramView;
```

I've tried to output the information using just the `fetchData` function however `this.el.append(response)` results in a notice saying that `el` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your `render` method is called before the fetching has completed. You should bind to the `sync` event of the collection and call render in the event handler.

```
social.InstagramView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#social',
    feed: {},
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new social.InstagramFeed();
        this.fetchData();
        this.collection.on('sync', function(){
          this.render();
        }, this);
        // this.render();
    },
...
})
```

Quoting Backbone.js documentation : sync event is fired :

> when a model or collection has been successfully synced with the server.